# How to get Firebase current user uid long after login?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and working in an angular project. I want to access the Firebase currentUser uid (on a component other than the login component).

After some searching I found that this can be done using Firebase `auth().onAuthStateChanged()` method after logging in. But this will allow me to access uid only once after logging in and also only in the login component. But I want that uid in another component.

I have to query my database using that uid. I could not find the best way to do it. One way I figured out was to save the uid and share it with the other component, but this doesn't seem a nice way to do it.

[image: My Firebase database looks like this]

The hierarchy is

```
uid-->random_id_1-->{data}
   -->random_id_2-->{data}
```

So to access the data I need the uid of current user. I want it in another angular component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the section aptly titled [Get the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the `Auth` object:
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

...

> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the `currentUser` property. If a user isn't signed in, currentUser is null:
>
> ```
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
> if (user) {
>   // User is signed in.
> } else {
>   // No user is signed in.
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I went through it several times earlier but I thought it will work only on the login component. I tried the same in another component and it worked. So basically whenever we want to access the currentUser (in another component ) we have to use this observer. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The first snippet above is an observer that gets called whenever the authentication state changes. You'd use this if you e.g. want to do something specifically when the user logs in out out. The second snippet **gets** the current user. You'd use this to check if the user is signed in or to get the user's identity (when you already *know* they're signed in).

Comment: Suppose I navigate to another component after logging in, then the second snippet results to null. By another component I mean another page. Now I am able to get currentUser in every component I navigate , using first snippet.